# I want to print each line on a different row

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

This is my code:
(I am trying to print a text file that contains song lyrics as an image. Using python turtle, drawing squares to represent pixels; printing this as the format of the lyrics in the textfile to make a picture.)

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
canvas=turtle.Screen()
canvas.setup(width=1280, height=720)
t.speed(0)

#The drawing starts in the upper left corner of the canvas.
t.penup()
t.goto(-600,325)
t.pendown()

def square(color):
    
    t.fillcolor(color)
    t.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(10)
        t.right(90)
    t.end_fill()


def paint_line (file_text):
    """
The paint line() function shall take one parameter as input, a string representing
a line from a text file, and draw a row of colorful squares corresponding to the
characters in the line.
After drawing the row, the turtle shall go to the beginning of the next row to be
ready to paint the next line, if any.
    """

    count=0
    for ch in file_text:
        count+=1
        if (ord(ch)<70):
            square('black')
        elif (ord(ch)>=70 and ord(ch)<100):
            square('pink')
        elif (ord(ch)>=100 and ord(ch)<110):
            square('light blue')
        elif (ord(ch)>=110 and ord(ch)<122):
            square('yellow')
        elif (ord(ch)>122):
            square('green')

        #to print each line of text on a different row
        t.penup()
        t.left(180)
        t.pendown()
    

#do not use readlines()
def picture(file_name):
    '''
The picture() function takes one parameter as input, a file name, opens the file,
and draws the picture by calling the paint line() function for each line of text in
the file. 
    '''
    file_data=open(file_name+".txt","r")
    file_text=file_data.readline()
    count=1
    while file_text:
        print("Line {}: {}".format(count, file_text.strip()))

        file_text=file_data.readline()
        paint_line(file_text)
        count += 1
        
    file_data.close() 

    

def main():
    '''
The main() function prompts the user for a file name and calls picture() to do
the work.
    '''      
    file_name=input("Enter the file Name")
    picture(file_name)

main()
```

This is what the text file contains:

> Strawberries, cherries and an angel kissing spring
> My summer wine is really made from all these things
> I walked in town on silver spurs that jingled to
> A song that I had only sang to just a few
> She saw my silver spurs and said let's pass some time
> And I will give to you, summer wine
> Oh. oh, oh, summer wine
> Strawberries, cherries and an angel kissing spring
> My summer wine is really made from all these things
> Take off your silver spurs and help me pass the time
> And I will give to you, summer wine
> Oh, summer wine
> My eyes grew heavy and my lips they could not speak
> I tried to get up but I couldn't find my feet
> She reassured me with the unfamiliar line
> And then she gave to me, more summer wine
> Woh, woh, oh, summer wine
> Strawberries, cherries and an angel kissing spring
> My summer wine is really made from all these things
> Take off your silver spurs and help me pass the time
> And I will give to you, summer wine
> Mm, summer wine
> When I woke up, the sun was shining in my eyes
> My silver spurs were gone, my head felt twice its size
> She took my silver spurs, a dollar and a dime
> And left me craving for, more summer wine
> Oh, oh, summer wine
> Strawberries, cherries and an angel kissing spring
> My summer wine is really made from all these things
> Take off those silver spurs, help me pass the time
> And I will give to you my summer wine
> Oh, oh, summer wine

[This is the output I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L42ZT.jpg)

[This is the output I expected:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfYmq.jpg)

Comment: What is the question? Does it not work? Do you get an error? Please fix some of the bad indentations in your code

Comment: It does not work as I want it to. I want the squares to look like the format of the song lyrics. Each square presents a letter in song lyrics.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed an example of your output and the output you expect and try to ask about a more specific problem

Comment: I just added pictures

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to reset your pen's position correctly.

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
canvas = turtle.Screen()
canvas.setup(width=1280, height=720)
t.speed(0)

#The drawing starts in the upper left corner of the canvas.
t.penup()
t.goto(-600, 325)
t.pendown()


def square(color):

t.fillcolor(color)
t.begin_fill()
for i in range(4):
t.forward(10)
t.right(90)
t.end_fill()
t.forward(10)


def paint_line(file_text):
"""
The paint line() function shall take one parameter as input, a string representing
a line from a text file, and draw a row of colorful squares corresponding to the
characters in the line.
After drawing the row, the turtle shall go to the beginning of the next row to be
ready to paint the next line, if any.
"""

count = 0
for ch in file_text:
count += 1
if (ord(ch) < 70):
square('black')
elif (ord(ch) >= 70 and ord(ch) < 100):
square('pink')
elif (ord(ch) >= 100 and ord(ch) < 110):
square('light blue')
elif (ord(ch) >= 110 and ord(ch) < 122):
square('yellow')
elif (ord(ch) > 122):
square('green')

#to print each line of text on a different row
t.penup()
# t.right(20)
t.pendown()


#do not use readlines()
def picture(file_name):
'''
The picture() function takes one parameter as input, a file name, opens the file,
and draws the picture by calling the paint line() function for each line of text in
the file.
'''
file_data = open(file_name + ".txt", "r")
file_text = file_data.readline()
count = 1
while file_text:
print("Line {}: {}".format(count, file_text.strip()))
file_text = file_data.readline()
paint_line(file_text)
t.penup()
t.goto(-600, 325 - count * 10)
t.pendown()
count += 1
file_data.close()


def main():
'''
The main() function prompts the user for a file name and calls picture() to do
the work.
'''
file_name = 'test'  #input("Enter the file Name")
picture(file_name)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with turning your turtle completely around instead of moving it forward, you've also skip over character 122 ('z') in your logic.

To both simplify the code, and speed up the program, I would approach this as a *stamping* problem rather than a *drawing* one:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1280, 720

TILE_SIZE = 10
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def square(color):

    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.stamp()

def paint_line(text):
    '''
    The paint line() function shall take one parameter as input, a string representing
    a line from a text file, and draw a row of colorful squares corresponding to the
    characters in the line.
    After drawing the row, the turtle shall go to the beginning of the next row to be
    ready to paint the next line, if any.
    '''

    for character in text:
        code = ord(character)

        if code < 70:
            square('black')
        elif 70 <= code < 100:
            square('pink')
        elif 100 <= code < 110:
            square('light blue')
        elif 110 <= code < 122:
            square('yellow')
        elif code >= 122:
            square('green')

        # to print each line of text on a different row
        turtle.forward(10)

#do not use readlines()
def picture(file_name):
    '''
    The picture() function takes one parameter as input, a file name, opens the file,
    and draws the picture by calling the paint line() function for each line of text in
    the file.
    '''

    with open(file_name + ".txt") as file_data:
        for line, text in enumerate(file_data, start=1):
            print("Line {}: {}".format(line, text.strip()))

            paint_line(text)

            turtle.goto(-WIDTH/2 + TILE_SIZE, turtle.ycor() - TILE_SIZE)

def main():
    '''
    The main() function prompts the user for a file name and calls picture() to do
    the work.
    '''

    file_name = input("Enter the file name: ")
    picture(file_name)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.shapesize(TILE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

# The drawing starts near the upper left corner of the canvas.
turtle.goto(-WIDTH/2 + TILE_SIZE, HEIGHT/2 - TILE_SIZE)

main()

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]